# Angular: Use Pipe to Format Date

Tags: angular

I have an elevator component.
Whenever the elevator reaches the first floor, store the date and display it in dd/MM/yy format.

```
if floor === 1 show Date
else
return(empty)
```

My [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zbrapb)

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: @TheFabio  Whenever the elevator reaches the first floor, store the date and display it in dd/MM/yy format.

Comment: @TuNguyen I tried, there is even what I wrote there and I tried a lot
It just does not work for me

Comment: @TuNguyen I can not convert the Observable <Number> to a number

Comment: you don't convert it... you should subscribe to the observable

Comment: A kindly reminder: You should post a minimal code for your question instead of link. The link is fragile and your question is not useful if the link is broken.

Comment: @YongShun The link works, and there is very little code I want to stand out on the GetDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert an observable to a number...

you need to subscribe to it:

```
interval(1000)
      .pipe(map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1))
      .subscribe((floor) => {
        this.floor = floor;
      });
```